# Change Layered Navigation Filter Output

Tags: layered-navigation, filter

I'm working on a problem at the moment in the layered navigation. I need to change how the filters are working. Currently they are called like so;

```
    $_filters = $this->getFilters();
    foreach ($_filters as $_filter):
    //various mark up and calls are made here
```

Then to output the individual options the following is used.

```
   $_filter->getHtml()
```

I need to find another way of getting this data, preferably unformatted. I am able to get each filters attribute code like so;

```
  $_filter->getFilterOptions()->getCode()
```

But I can't figure out how to use this to get the options belonging to each filter attribute.

The two most important pieces of information that I need are the option name and id. After this I can work everything out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an array called $data which contains the filter code. Using this I was able to get what I needed. Here is the code.

```
   foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $attribute_details = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute('catalog_product',    $key);

           foreach ($attribute_details->getSource()->getAllOptions(false) as $key2 => $value) {

                   $datam[$key][0] .= '<span class="filter" id="'. $value['value'] . ' ' . $key .'">'.$value['label'].'</span>';
           }
   }
```

$Datam is the new array and $key is the filter code.

Answer (score 2):

The output of `$_filter->getHtml()` can be found in `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml` (filter items).